# File upload on AWS S3 using the AdminJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, adminjs, admin-bro

I am creating an administrator panel using AdminJs. I want to upload files on my S3 bucket. For that, I am using awsProvider.

I am getting an error `Could not load credentials from any providers.`

Here is the screenshot of the code.

```
    import model from "../models/wallpapers.model.js";
    import { mongooseDB } from "../mongoConnection.js";
    import { Components, componentLoader } from "../frontend/components.js";
    import uploadFeature, { AWSOptions } from '@adminjs/upload';

    const localProvider = {
        bucket: 'public/files',
        opts: {
            baseUrl: '/files',
        },
    };
    const awsProvider: AWSOptions = {
        accessKeyId: '<accessKey>',
        secretAccessKey: '<secret_key>',
        region: '<region>',
        bucket: '<bucket name>',
    }

    export const WallpapersResourceOptions = {
        databases: [mongooseDB],
        resource: model,
        options: {
            properties: {
                image: {
                    isVisible: { create: false, list: true, show: true },
                    components: {
                        list: Components.ImageBox,
                        show: Components.ImageBox,
                    }
                },
                file: {
                    isVisible: {
                        list: false,
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                createdAt: { isVisible: false },
                updatedAt: { isVisible: false },
                _id: { isVisible: false },
                isDeleted: { isVisible: false },
            }
        },
        features: [
            uploadFeature({
                provider: {
                    aws: awsProvider
                    // local: localProvider,
                },
                validation: { mimeTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] },
                componentLoader: componentLoader,
                properties: {
                    key: "image",
                    mimeType: "mimeType",
                    filePath: "/files",
                },
                uploadPath: (record: any, filename: string) => {
                    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(record))
                    // const json = JSON.parse(data)
                    const folderName = data?.populated?.projectId?.title
                    return `${folderName}/${filename}`;
                },
            }),
        ],
    };
```

Error Log

```
         CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
            at /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-cjs/defaultProvider.js:13:11
            at /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/chain.js:12:39
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
            at async coalesceProvider (/Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:14:24)
            at async SignatureV4.credentialProvider (/Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:33:24)
            at async SignatureV4.signRequest (/Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/SignatureV4.js:106:29)
            at async /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:16:18
            at async /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
            at async /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:57:20
            at async /Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
            at async updateRecord (file:///Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/build/features/upload-file/factories/update-record-factory.js:75:17)
            at async file:///Users/jaykukadiya/Desktop/Projects/Work/music-adminJs/node_modules/@adminjs/express/lib/buildRouter.js:24:22
```

I tried fileupload using localprovider and it's working fine.
I pass correct AWS S3 credentials. I cross checked with a separate Node.js project developed in [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please post your code and logs in text format. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the full content of `awsProvider` (obviously without sensitive data)

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this updated version, we have replaced the previous awsProvider object with the new structure as you specified for the newer version of the AWS package. This object now contains the necessary credentials, region, and bucket information.

```
const awsProvider = {
     credentials: {
        accessKeyId: '<accessKey>',
        secretAccessKey: '<secret_key>',
     },
     region: '<region>',
     bucket: '<bucket name>',
}
```

Comment: This looks like a ChatGPT response that solved your problem?  It doesn't appear to be totally based on information that you presented in your question, which leads me to believe that you left some of the troubleshooting information out.  I'm happy to hear that you have resolved your issue, but you should make sure that there's enough information here for *others* to be able to resolve the same issue - I don't think there is at the moment.

Comment: Related: [xkcd 979](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients)